# Multiple Dex Files Exception in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

All of a sudden I am getting the following error in my project in Android Studio.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4/dx --dex --output /Users/azamsharp/AndroidStudioProjects/SLB/app/build/dex/debug /Users/azamsharp/AndroidStudioProjects/SLB/app/build/classes/debug /Users/azamsharp/AndroidStudioProjects/SLB/app/build/dependency-cache/debug /Users/azamsharp/AndroidStudioProjects/SLB/app/build/pre-dexed/debug/android-async-http-1.4.4-ebbcd48910e41cec52d1452a5743c94a9159f5e1.jar /Users/azamsharp/AndroidStudioProjects/SLB/app/build/pre-dexed/debug/android-support-v4-6c3868a97cf3c20d5a1f7a32bd415e4ceb4d85e8.jar /Users/azamsharp/AndroidStudioProjects/SLB/app/build/pre-dexed/debug/classes-8df088fb881a9b300721edc9635f1f9db6ecf298.jar /Users/azamsharp/AndroidStudioProjects/SLB/app/build/pre-dexed/debug/gcm-dd10621f5a27ca99ec0a973a9d3d24df75dabba1.jar /Users/azamsharp/AndroidStudioProjects/SLB/app/build/pre-dexed/debug/support-v4-19.0.1-3bf117e59e2e0f41bbf9219f2be90cdcf1dd583d.jar
  Error Code:
    2
  Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:593)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:551)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:532)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:169)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:187)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

I did not even do anything with the references. I simply added an Activity and then deleted it shortly after.

Comment: Have you added any library project to your main project.

Comment: Not recently! I added it 2-3 weeks back.

Comment: I think problem is you have multiple android support v4 jar files in your project. Do one thing remove android support v4 jar from your main project and add library project's android support v4 jar to your project.

Comment: This is what bothers me! I was running the project since 2-3 weeks now. I added a activity and then I deleted that activity and then this problem start coming. Really weird!!!

Comment: I commented out  // compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+' and not it compiles and works!

Comment: I had a same issue few day's back and used above solution and that tricks works for me.

Comment: appcompat-v7 includes support-v4, so if you have the former, you don't need the latter.

Comment: Ah, and may I ask how do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

ok , I have the same problem and here is the solution:

Go to "Build" in the top and "Clean Project" and after "Rebuild the project"
It helps me!
Also you can go to "Files" and Invalidate caches" and restart the Android Studio

Of corse be sure that manifest is ok and no duplicate includes!