# Getting: "Multiple dex files define Landroid[...]" error in recently moved Android project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I just moved an android project from Eclipse to Android Studio and when I try to debug it, throws this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.  
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:  
    /Users/Emmanuel/Google Drive/Projects/Eclipse/AndroidSDK/build-tools/21.1.1/dx --dex --output /Users/Emmanuel/Google Drive/Projects/Android Studio/Tactical Defence/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug /Users/Emmanuel/Google Drive/Projects/Android Studio/Tactical Defence/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug /Users/Emmanuel/Google Drive/Projects/Android Studio/Tactical Defence/app/build/intermediates/dependency-cache/debug /Users/Emmanuel/Google Drive/Projects/Android Studio/Tactical Defence/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/android-support-v13-f8677cc4846d11342a88325560382f359de0a07e.jar /Users/Emmanuel/Google Drive/Projects/Android Studio/Tactical Defence/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/android-support-v17-leanback-d6c643830d064b23379bf1f172ba90becf3ebd44.jar /Users/Emmanuel/Google Drive/Projects/Android Studio/Tactical Defence/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-207146703249fd55fd38f32ceb1e7dccc249cb34.jar /Users/Emmanuel/Google Drive/Projects/Android Studio/Tactical Defence/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-459868113001e4cec1eea525caf42f86a2b30065.jar /Users/Emmanuel/Google Drive/Projects/Android Studio/Tactical Defence/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/internal_impl-21.0.0-819542c28fb9bc818114b11c85096586a67ba269.jar /Users/Emmanuel/Google Drive/Projects/Android Studio/Tactical Defence/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/support-annotations-21.0.0-5b4790f7f590ff544b24825092f52bd5c5fc446d.jar  
  Error Code:  
    2  
  Output:  
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:  
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;  
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)  
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)  
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)  
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)  
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)  
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)  
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:302)  
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:245)  
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)  
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

I tried to:

> 1. As suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21100040/3124150 (comment #9)
>      run:
>      ./gradlew -q :app:dependencies
>      Got:

```
compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.  
\--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0  
     \--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0  
          \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.0
```

> 2. As suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24511114/3124150
>      "Build">"Clean Project" and after "Rebuild the project". Also tried,  "Files">"Invalidate caches" and restart the Android Studio

Couldn't solve the problem...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Look into your lib folder, there is probably the support library jar. Delete and try again

Comment: @zapl deleted all in "libs" folder, problem soved. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing what @zapl said:"Look into your lib folder, there is probably the support library jar. Delete and try again" (1rst comment to the question) solved my problem.